# JSON will load just one value

Tags: java, android, json

Well problem is while JSON reads file in load method. I will describe in the coments. 
NOTE: many code is omitted for more clear view

```
private static final String ID = "moti_data";

public static void save(Context context) throws IOException, JSONException {
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    for (int i = 0; i < notify1.length; i++)
        obj.put("n1_" + i, notify1[i]);
    arr.put(obj);
    //while testing ar.toString() was arr[{"n1_0":1,"n1_1":15,"n1_2":23,"n1_3":0}]
    //it is clear that it contains 4 values but arr.length() will give 1
    String file = arr.toString();
    FileOutputStream output = context.openFileOutput(ID, MODE_PRIVATE);
    output.write(file.getBytes());
    output.close();
}
```

then problems persists in load method since i can get just one value out of it. Also all others values are incorrect - 0. So when i have managed to make it word for few minutes output was arr[{"n1_0":1,"n1_1":0,"n1_2":0,"n1_3":0}]. S0 just first value is correct

```
public static void load(Context context) throws IOException, JSONException {
    //reading data
    FileInputStream input = context.openFileInput(ID);
    BufferedInputStream bi = new BufferedInputStream(input);
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (bi.available() != 0) {
        char c = (char) bi.read();
        buffer.append(c);
    }
    bi.close();
    input.close();
    //JSON
    JSONArray data = new JSONArray(buffer.toString());
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) 
        notify1[i] = data.getJSONObject(i).getInt("n1_" + i);
}
```

So whatever i do/have tried i get one loop and json exception. But as i initialy tought problem is not in saving since outputs were good. Or am i wrong?

EDDIT: there are 6 blocks of 4 values in code (here is just one for clarity). Also i cant hardcode them since values are ment to be changed by the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSONArray only contains one JSONObject:

```
[
 { "n1_0":1,
   "n1_1":15,
   "n1_2":23,
   "n1_3":0
 } //finish data.getJSONObject(0);
]
```

To access to every value on the JSONObject you should do:

```
JSONObject object = data.getJSONObject(0);
for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++)
    notify1[i] = object.getInt("n1_" + i);
```

I use https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com to see the JSON hierarchy in a clear way. Hope I solved your problem.

Comment: well with a bit of modification it did. Thanks for insight

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating through objects, but not through their parameters. You could iterate through your object parameters like this:

```
JSONArray data = new JSONArray(buffer.toString());
for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) 
    for (int j = 0; j < myParametherCount; j++) 
        notify1[i] = data.getJSONObject(i).getInt("n1_" + j);
        //note that you have to edit which element of the notify1 list you will use to store this data
```

Where `myParametherCount` is the count of parameters one object will have.

You are getting an exception on your 5th object where you are trying to excess the 5th element of the list which is undefined (in this example).

Comment: I edited my answer. Basically, you were iterating just through objects, not through their parameters

Comment: y i see. Thank you